# Фанфикшн или фэнфикшн?

Tags: орфография

Я понимаю, что такого слова в словарях нет, но как-то его писать все же приходится. Так вот, как правильнее: через А или через Э (или вообще через Е)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если слова нет в словаре, надо гуглить. А Гугл говорит, что гораздо больше вариантов с "а", чем с "э". Кроме того, в Википедии есть слово ["фанфик"](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA) (очевидно, то же, что и "фанфикшн"), где сказано, что допускается и "фэнфик" ("фэнфикшн"). Но поскольку англ. слово fan (поклонник) прижилось в русском как ["фан"](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%F4%E0%ED&all=x), а не "фэн" и тем более не "фен" (это будет уже прибор для сушки волос), поэтому логично писать и произносить "фанфикшн" через "а", а не через "э".